# Replacing string including a metacharacter

Tags: replace

I am learning to use VIM to write Python code. Frequently, I need to perform replacements that include metacharacters, e.g. replacing all instances of '2**NN' with 'MM'. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to match a literal *, you can escape the `*` metacharacter with backslashes:

```
:%s/2\*\*NN/MM
```

See the user manual for an introduction to Vim's search/replace functionality:

```
:h usr_27.txt
```

The reference manual contains more detailed information on Vim's regular expressions:

```
:h regexp
```